# File recovery from phone went wrong, seems to have damaged laptop drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

I decided to recover some files I had recently deleted from a micro SD card in an old Nokia. I connected the phone to my laptop, downloaded TestDisk, and for some reason or another I selected all files that TestDisk found on the card (even if some of them were 0 bytes in size).

The card is a mere 1 GB in size, yet the folder on my Desktop where stuff was copied somehow ended up being 9 GB in size, and my Windows 7 started moving a bit slower than usual. The free space on C: drive went from 60 to 51 GB; after browsing the recovered contents I decided to delete the folder, only to run into some problems.

Currently, the folder is 0 bytes in size, and contains some files also 0 bytes in size. I cannot delete/rename/etc any of them ("Could not find this item. This is no longer located in [...]") and the free space on C: did not go back to 60 GB.

`chkdsk` did not identify any errors, yet the numbers still don't add up.
[The output of WinDirStat](https://i.imgur.com/36iZcYz.png) plus the [System Restore points](https://i.imgur.com/38GTYEf.png) don't seem to take as much as it says it does (54.1 GB free out of 99.9 GB total, hence 45.8 used).

Also, System Restore throws an "unspecified error" upon completion and changes nothing.

Is there anything I missed? Could it be that the hard drive is corrupted?

`chkdsk` output:

```
 104755199 KB total disk space.
  47730864 KB in 76077 files.
     53724 KB in 24619 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    305559 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  56665052 KB available on disk.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ultimately managed to solve the problem. It seems either that TestDisk corrupted a part of the filesystem, or that the extracted contents themselves did that. For anyone who might run into a similar problem (**a hierarchy of files that refuse to be deleted**), try this:

Open `cmd` with administrative rights, and `cd` into the parent directory of the corrupted hierarchy. Imagine the hierarchy as a tree where the leaves are either files or empty folders, then:

- manually `cd` into the parent nodes of every leaf;
- use `ren` to rename the leaf (anything will do);
- use `del` to delete it; delete all the children of a node before advancing upwards;
- repeat this process until the hierarchy no longer exists.

After every deletion check the empty space on the affected partition; I watched mine grow back in random amounts, until it stabilized at the amount before the transfer.

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution after almost two years.

Comment: Thanks. I had solved this a few days after, and forgot about this question. My bad here.